# Best way to sync VBOs between threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, opengl, graphics

So I have a minecraft-like chunk system, meaning it's one block of render data. When the player moves around and enters another chunk, out-of-range chunks are being unloaded while new ones are being loaded, which makes it quite demanding since render data has to be calculated in another thread first before it can be shown.

Assuming the data is already loaded from the disk it looks like this

Main/Render Thread           Render Data Generation Thread

```
   |         Request Chunk            |
   | -------------------------------> |
   |                                  |
   |                                  | Generating render data (FloatBuffer)
   |                                  |
   |                                  .
   |                                  .
   |                                  .
   |        Get Ready Chunks          |
   | <------------------------------- |
   |                                  |
   | Upload Data                      |
   |                                  |
   | Render                           |
   |                                  |
```

"Request Chunk" and "Get Ready Chunks" are not synchronized so the render thread really works independently.

The problem with this is that uploading a lot of chunks at once causes framedrops, but calculating how much time I have left to upload can't be done reliably. If I only uploade one per frame I would miss out on alot of speed, although it works fine (That's how it's implemented at the moment).

Since I'm using only one GL context I can only create VBOs in the main thread at the moment.

Is there any way to solve this to be more efficently, like creating VBOs in the other thread and just passing them over to the main thread?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly your approach of limiting the number of uploads per frame is probably the way to go; even commercial games I've worked on do this to avoid streaming hitches. Do all the work you possibly can in other threads, and then only the submission itself in your rendering thread.

One useful thing to speed this up might be to think about ways to reduce the amount of data you actually have to upload per-chunk. E.g., in my own voxel renderer the chunk size is 64x64x64, which means I only really need 8 bits per component for the positions (with a couple bits to spare). And I can save having to submit normals by computing them from derivatives in the pixel shader. And so on.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, OpenGL is by its nature single-threaded. As such you can only go OpenGL calls from a single thread. You can load a chunk in the background in a separate thread (as you should with blocking I/O), but ultimately uploading it to the graphics card will need to happen from the main OpenGL thread.

One thing you can do is using `glBufferSubData()`. It allows you to upload your chunk of geometry in pieces as opposed to all at once. I don't quite think you'll be able to get rid of hitches entirely, so perhaps you can try to transfer a constant amount of geometry per frame while you are loading a chunk, so you can at least spread the process out over multiple frames.

Comment: You can actually create/share buffer between threads by using shared contexts as explained, for example, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912986/opengl-vbo-within-multiple-threads), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495109/multiple-context-with-different-version) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116305/opengl-secondary-thread-for-loading-resources/8126219#8126219).

Comment: Well, there's something I didn't know about. I'll look into this.

Comment: @BDL: From what I'm reading (also on pages other than the one you linked), multiple contexts will under the hood still be converted into serial OpenGL calls by most drivers. So apart from the ability of being able to upload resources to OpenGL at will, at a cost of an OpenGL context switch performance penalty, is there another reason why using multiple contexts is better? To me it appears that streaming and smearing out resource loading over multiple frames is better.

Comment: I personally would do both. You are absolutely right, that under the hood GPU commands have to be serialized. But in most cases, an operation consists of a CPU and a GPU part. When loading data, there is often a application to driver memory copy operation and a possible a format conversion involved which can in case of multiple threads be executed in parallel. Whether shared contexts provide better performance than a single on can only be profiled for the specific case.

Comment: There's an interesting reading at [OpenGL Insights](http://openglinsights.com/) in the chapter 28, free for download.